# Не работают статические файлы в django rest framework

Tags: python, django

После деплоя на сервер перестали применяться статические файлы - нет css. Вот настройки статики:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR]
```

Comment: collectstatic выполнили? Раздачу файлов из STATIC_ROOT настроили?

Comment: @andreymal, collectstatic выполнял, а что за раздача файлов?

Comment: Django не раздаёт статические файлы, это должен делать ваш веб-сервер

Comment: @andreymal, вы про nginx?

Comment: Если ваш веб-сервер это nginx, то видимо да

Comment: @andreymal, у меня в конфигурации nginx есть директива для статических файлов:
location /static/ {
        root /home/ilya/webion;
    }
я изменил настройки django и еще раз выполнил collectstatic, теперь в каталоге /home/ilya/webion/static находятся статические файлы, но все равно не применяются, в чем может быть проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что означает «не применяются»? Что происходит вместо ожидаемого вами поведения?

Comment: @andreymal, выводится голый html без стилей

Comment: Ссылка на стили сгенерировалась правильная? Что будет если открыть эту ссылку напрямую?

Comment: @andreymal, по ней ничего нет - not found

Comment: А в логах nginx при этом что написано?

Comment: @andreymal, permission denied:

[error] 520#520: *165 open() "/home/ilya/webion/static/admin/css/dashboard.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: *.*.*.*, server: *.*.*.*, request: "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1", host: "webion.pro", referrer: "https://webion.pro/admin/"

Например, админка подтягивает статические файлы, а nginx видимо не разрешает. В инструментах разработчика пишет, что код 404